# Why does Firebase observeEventType return a snapshot everytime in viewWillAppear?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that is observed on `viewWillAppear` on View Controller A

```
let query = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("tags").
    queryOrdered(byChild: "users/uid").queryEqual(toValue: userId)
```

In the same view controller, in `viewDidDisappear` I remove this observer.

So let's say I push into another view controller from View Controller A.

When I come back to View Controller A, the observer returns a snapshot, even though my data on the backend hasn't changed.

I only want a snapshot returning if there's been some actual change to my database. How do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying that in controllerA the code in your question is executed. Then when the user moves to controllerB from controllerA, the observer is removed. Then when moving back to controllerA the above code is executed again? Whenever you attach an observer, a snapshot is returned because the 'new' observer doesn't know about the data- it was removed and then a 'new' observer was added so to it, so the data is new. There may be no reason to remove it. If the array is kept an array alive when moving from A to B, just let the observer update it so when you get back to A, the data is current.

Comment: Yes you understood my scenario correctly.

But here's the problem I see:
1. I'm making unnecessary network calls just to "find out" if my snapshot has changed or not, which I think is expensive?
2. My tableview which displays this snapshot is being reloaded everytime now, which is not ideal. 

Any thoughts on these 2 points? I appreciate your response.

EDIT:
The reason I remove the observer in viewDidDisappear is because this article tells me to do so: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is to simply let the observer do it's job and update your data in the background.

So if the user is on controllerA the observer updates a datasource (an array) so then the UI is updated from that array.

When the user switches to controllerB, the observer can still update the array, but don't update the UI in controllerA since there's no need to.

When the user switches back to A you'll have current data available so just reload the tableView (assuming iOS here) from the array.

This solution reduces the 'polling' nature and let's Firebase do the heavy lifting to notify your app when it needs to. You're just reloading the tableViews from an array when that controller becomes active.

Edit

The idea here is to add the observer once - perhaps when the view loads the *first time only* (viewDidLoad) or maybe in your app delegate. Once you add the observer it will update your dataSource arrays when data changes so when you move from view to view the only action needed will be to reload the tableView from the updated array.

There are times when you may want to remove an observer but it doesn't sound like you need to do that from your question. So - attach the observers once and let them update the dataSource arrays as the data changes. Reload your tableViews when switching views.

Comment: Are there potential performance issues of making a network call to Firebase **everytime** controllerA calls viewWillAppear? This seems incredibly inefficient if your snapshot could potentially include hundreds of cell data.

Comment: @Woodless My solution avoids that completely, since you only add the observer once. So say in your app delegate you add the observers and Firebase will quietly update your arrays in the background so when you switch views in your UI, you will only need to reload the tableView to display the current data from the arrays. i.e. don't add the observer every time your viewDidAppear - only add it once. I will make that a little more clear in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- You have put the query in viewWillAppear, which means every time you come to viewController A, this query will be executed irrespective of you have removed the observer or not.
- Try putting the same query in viewDidLoad which means, the query will be called once and don't remove the observer anywhere. Now the query would be called only when data gets changed in firebase.